# Amazon SNS java - custom headers?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I would like to know how to set custom headers for Amazon SNS. The idea is to somehow distinguish Amazon notifications with type `Notification` sent to my http endpoint (not necessarily via headers), something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/webhook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void foo(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    if (request.getHeader("Custom-Header") != null)
    {
        // do something
    }

    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

If this is not possible with headers, how can I achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the headers which SNS sets in the request to determine if it came from amazon.

Refer this link: [AWS SNS HTTP Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/json-formats.html#http-header)